# Render HTML in Angular 15

Tags: angular

In Angular 15.2 I am trying to create a component that takes as input a string that contains valid HTML and renders this HTML.
The first attempt was attempting to use the ElementRef and innerHTML like this:

```
constructor(
  private readonly componentElement: ElementRef,
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  (this.componentElement.nativeElement as HTMLElement).innerHTML = html;
}
```

This renders the message `SafeValue must use [property]=binding:` and some of the HTML contained in the `html` variable.

So I tried to solve this by using the DomSanitizer:

```
constructor(
  private readonly sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
  private readonly componentElement: ElementRef,
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  const safer = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  (this.componentElement.nativeElement as HTMLElement).innerHTML = safer;
}
```

This generates the error: `Type 'SafeHtml' is not assignable to type 'string'`.

So I changed my approach by using the `Renderer2`:

```
constructor(
  private readonly sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
  private readonly componentElement: ElementRef,
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  const safer = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  this.renderer.setProperty(this.componentElement.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', safer)
}
```

This renders, again, the message `SafeValue must use [property]=binding:` and some of the HTML contained in the html variable.

I just can't get it to work!
I did all this to avoid having to print on the dom an HTML wrapper element that has inside it the property `[innerHTML]`. So I don't accept answers that propose to dirty the DOM with unnecessary elements like a wrapper.

Here is the [link for stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-15-starter-pack-xtqzr6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: please share a minimal stackblitz with the issue you are facing and what the expected output should be!

Comment: this.element.nativeElement.innerHTML = '<h1>...</h1>' ... but still a bad approach

Comment: And what exactly you are trying to insert? Because besides some really weird stuff it just works even without involving a sanitizer.

Comment: @ThomasRenger It is! But I have no other idea of how to render HTML stored in database, since it's coming form another company.

Comment: @Shlang I have to render valid HTML which comes from backend. I can't control what they are inserting. But it should be icons, paragraph, lists, links, nothing too weird (hopefully).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Thomas Renger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78239367/render-html-in-angular-15#comment137935988_78239367) and [Shlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78239367/render-html-in-angular-15#comment137937016_78239367) comments I was able to find the problem and solve it. Thanks guys!

The problem was that the `html` variable was not of type string but an object returned by `DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml()` and so printing the object directly produced the message `SafeValue must use [property]=binding:`.

This problem was solved by simply accessing the `changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity` property of the above object, like this:

```
(this.componentElement.nativeElement as HTMLElement).innerHTML = html['changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity']
```

Comment: Well, you don't need to call a `sanitizer` for "normal" HTML, and if HTML you're trying to insert does not appear it means it contains something really dangerous. Check this [playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-y2e6fk)